# How can I copy a list of the open tab titles in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, tabs, firefox-addon, title, add-on

I've been trying to copy a list of the open tab titles in Firefox, but I cannot seem to find a solution.

The closest I've came is by using: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/send-tab-urls/

But this add-on copies other details in addition to the tab titles.

I cannot find a solution anywhere for this simple task.

**Does anybody have any tips on how to accomplish this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Multiple Tab Handler addon.  Right click, then *Copy URI of All Tabs*.  You will need to tweak the addon's options to output the result in the format you want.

Or alternatively, open up Firefox's Scratchpad developer tool (Shift-F4) and use the following code in `browser` environment.

```js
// -sp-context: browser
var tabs=Array.from(gBrowser.visibleTabs);
var urls=tabs.map(t=>gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(t).currentURI.spec);
var titles=tabs.map(t=>gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(t).contentTitle);
urls.join("\n");
titles.join("\n");
```

The variable `titles` will contain the array of titles of the currently visible tabs (i.e. tabs in the current tab group).  Use *Display* to view the contents of the variable.

Comment: I don't believe this works anymore. I keep getting `gBrowser is not defined`.

Comment: gBrowser is not defined, should I use another object?

Answer (score 1):

Simple ..... here is an example

```js
for (var i = 0, len = window.gBrowser.tabs.length; i < len; i++) {
  
  console.log(window.gBrowser.tabs[i].label);

}
```

There are a few more tab related functions in my [FoxyTab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/foxytab/)

Comment: @goatmeal  It is JavaScript but it is in browser scope. You can use it in a Firefox  addon but not in a script like GreaseMonkey script.